# Can't select root node from XmlElement

Tags: c#, xml

I deleted my last, poorly worded question and boiled it down to the simplest form. I am trying to select a root node, but it's coming back as null.

Here's my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <children>
    <child>Clark</child>
    <child>Bruce</child>
    <child>Peter</child>
  </children>
</root>
```

And here's my code

```
XmlDocument input = new XmlDocument();
XmlDocument output = new XmlDocument();

input.Load(@"simple.xml");

XmlNode outputNode = output.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, input.ChildNodes[1].Name, null);

Console.WriteLine(outputNode.SelectSingleNode("root") == null ? "null" : "node found"); 
Console.WriteLine(outputNode.SelectSingleNode("/root") == null ? "null" : "node found"); 
Console.WriteLine(outputNode.SelectSingleNode("//root") == null ? "null" : "node found"); 

//After doing this, /root and //root return the root node
output.AppendChild(node);

Console.WriteLine(outputNode.SelectSingleNode("root") == null ? "null" : "node found"); 
Console.WriteLine(outputNode.SelectSingleNode("/root") == null ? "null" : "node found"); 
Console.WriteLine(outputNode.SelectSingleNode("//root") == null ? "null" : "node found");
```

EDIT: @Marc put me on the right track. Actually adding the node to XmlDocument made it work

Comment: It looks to me like outputNode might actually be your children node because of the .ChildNodes[1]...worth a look maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a new *orphan* node (i.e. not yet in the tree), without any descendants. It is reasonable that your queries *relative to that orphan* don't find anything.

To find existing nodes, look at `.DocumentElement`, `.SelectSingleNode(...)` and `SelectNodes(...)`